# Raspberry pi - How to use Arduino Nano CH340 with Windows IOT

Tags: c#, arduino, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to get data from usb serial. **Sharp GP2Y0A02YK0F** sensor connect with Arduino CH340. Its connect to Raspberry pi via usb. I cant get data because Windows IOT not found usb serial port. Is there a any driver or any alternative way how to use sharp sensor with windows IOT.

p.s : I already tried FTDI but it won be fix it. I install it correctly but when I try to get info via  **devcon status "USB\VID_0403&PID_6001"**  its return no found device

Thanx.

Comment: It looks like you completely forgot to proofread your question.  You say "I can get data" -- if you are getting data successfully, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I mean " can't " - Problem is Raspberry pi can't find device ( usb serial port Arduino CH340). I fix it with PDCF 8591 (ADC) and getting data from I2C

Comment: Have you tried the FTDI 232R USB-To-Serial driver I was talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm attaching FTDI 232R USB-To-Serial to Rapsberry Pi 2 USB port running fresh windows IoT Core 10.0.10586.0. No additional device driver is installed, the FT232R USB UART is correctly recognized,

[image]

For code samples using serial ports, refer to https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialSample. I have verified it works with IoT version 10.0.10586.0 and above.